# Windows 10 Taskbar is freezing for 10-20 minutes

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm an IT intern at a company and we have a lot of workers suffering from this problem.They're going out for a lunch break for 45 minutes,they're leaving computers on until they start to work again.Then lunch break ends,they try to work again but they see that taskbar isn't working.We tried sending several Windows updates and other solutions but we couldn't solve it permanently.All of the workers are using Windows 10.
We should find a proper solution for this because people can't work for 20 mins in a day.
Is it because of the computer uptime?
**we don't have a lot time to fix it when it happens,so if it has any short-time solution,we would be happy to do that.**

Comment: What happens during these 45 minutes? Is the screen locked or do the computers sleep?

Comment: What third party shell extensions have been installed?  These can freeze the taskbar (which is part of the explorer).  There is probably 3rd party stuff that all employees have installed by the company.. or perhaps just something they all like.

Comment: @harrymc they're just screenlocked.

Comment: Is it a standard screenlock? How is it created and with which parameters?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas i don't have any idea about that but I'll try to figure it out

Comment: @harrymc it's the original screenlock of windows.They activate it with the win+L buttons.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas i asked it to my co-worker and he said that we don't use any third party extensions so it's probably not related to that but thank you a lot.

Comment: I would bet money your coworker is incorrect.  Perhaps that person is not the one to go to for advice.  [This simple tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) will show you what is loaded.  In the one answer below.. "context item" is not the correct term as he is referring to a shell extension but he is not wrong.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks a lot,i'll try it with the test computers.

Answer (score 0):

> We should find a proper solution for this because people can't work
> for 20 mins in a day. Is it because of the computer uptime?

This issue is most likely because of a context item gone wrong. I have seen this before. It is not because of computer uptime.  I left my Windows 10 machines on 24x7 and now my Windows 11 machines on 24x7

**First,** context extensions (WinMerge, SysInternals, and like, Java, Office and so on) all should  be 64-bit versions. Get rid of 32-bit software.

**Second,** try on one machine a Windows 10 Repair Install and use the option to Keep Everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**Third**, if a Keep Everything Repair does not work:

Then on this test machine, something has gone wrong with the Operating System that defies repair, or the Windows User Profile is damaged.

Back Up and do a fresh install of Windows 10.

Try the above on one or two machines and then prepare a Repair Strategy based on the above.

Comment: thank you a lot i'll try what you say.

Comment: I mean no offense but there is no such thing as a "context shell".  It is called a shell extension and providing context menus to the shell are one of the many things that it can do.

Comment: Edited to fix - thank you.  Big issue is adopting 64-bit Apps for these things.